# placing citations at the end of sentence

Tags: citing

Is it possible to move all the citations that i have cited to appear at the end of the line in the compiled pdf doc.

For example if i do

```
The common \cite{cite1} trend in much of the preceding work is that
```

the citation will come right after the word common and before trend

Is there a method where i can say globally to make all the citations appear at the end, without having to manually move them ?

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want the citation at the end of the line or at the end of the sentence?

Comment: end of the sentence

Comment: I'm not sure it is a good idea in general. Suppose you have a sentence: the results in \cite{ref1} are a generalization of those in \cite{ref2}. Moving the citations at the end you would loose the information.

Comment: the problem arises when iam going from ieee style to apa style. When i have a sentence such as:->  According to "Li \cite{Li}" this gets translated to :- "According to Li (Li, 2010)". This doesnt look right. I can make it look alot better if i can move the citations to the end of the sentence

Answer (score 4):

The easiest thing to do would be to use

```
The common\marginpar{\cite{cite1}} trend in much of the preceding work is that
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution would be to use `\citet` instead of `\cite` and loading the `natbib` or `biblatex` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{li,
  author = "Li, Li",
  title = "Some title",
  year = 2012,
  journal = "Some Journal"
}  
\end{filecontents}

%% for ieee (numeric) citation style
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

%% for apa (author-date) citation style
%\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

According to \citet{li} text.

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}  
\end{document}
```